# How can users check their NFTs after they minted NFTs via <CrossmintPayButton>?

Tags: nft, crossmint

I implemented to make users mint NFTs via . But I have got one issue.
How can I make users check their NFTs after their minting?
For example, when I click , a new window connecting to crossmint is opened and I pay money via credit card and at the end, I can check them on the collection page on this window. I want to know how users can check NFTs on the collection page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crossmint team member here.

In case the person didn't have a wallet and the NFT was minted to their email address directly, they can view their NFTs through the Crossmint website - link [here](https://www.crossmint.com/user/collection). They can also transfer that NFT to a non-custodial wallet like Metamask or Phantom from there.

In addition to this, you could add [Crossmint Connect](https://docs.crossmint.com/docs/setup-and-usage) to your site. Crossmint Connect will allow users to connect their Crossmint account to your site, so you can show them the NFTs they are holding directly in your frontend.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question. I added Crossmint Connect to my site. But it only returned users's Public Key. How can I make users connect their collection page using that button like crossmintPayButton? One more... How can I set API_KEY in crossmint connect button? Although I set API_KEY as "" or "asdf"(random),  the connect function results are always same. Could you teach me about these issues?

Comment: Hi! This is the intended functionality of Crossmint Connect.

You can use the public key now to query the blockchain and display the assets that the user is holding in their Crossmint wallet.

Let me know if I can help further!